# How to override json_encode() functionality in php

Tags: php, json

I have created total api's using php programming, for the output i used

```
json_encode($arr),
```

Now i want to  print output as pretty print format
in the browser without using JSON Viewer extensions..

I have already completed 400+ webservices using json_encode($arr) to output, but i don't want to change to

```
 echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I just want how to override the default json_encode() predefined functionality to full fill my need..

Comment: `echo "<pre/>"; echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: echo "<pre/>"; echo json_encode($arr,true);

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>", print_r(json_encode($arr)), "</pre>";`

Comment: If i did as per you i need to modify in all the 400+ apis, i don't want to change, i just want to override functionality with one place of action

Comment: then create a function but then you have to call that function also on that 400+places

Comment: Did you checked override_function function?

Comment: before writing code only you could written a function with return JSON value.......this might have reduced your 400+ apis depedency

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other solution without redefine the json_encode function, you could also simply register an output handler, which reads the printed json and print it again in pretty.

```
ob_start(function($json) {
    return json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
});
```

Benefit of this solution would be, you don't need any php extensions (as runkit currently dont work in PHP 7)

Comment: but is a little bit expensive: you have to encode, decode and re-encode the same thing

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways to do that by using some extensions like `runkit` which provide `runkit_function_redefine()` or `apd` which provide `override_function()`.

If I were you, I'd simply find/replace the `json_encode()` calls, adding `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.

Comment: yes using override_function we can achieve required

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`override_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) like this:

```
rename_function('json_encode', 'original_json_encode');
override_function('json_encode', '$value, $options = 128, $depth = 512', 'return original_json_encode($value, $options, $depth);');
```

in this way you can use the original one to get the result, overriding the default options (128 is the value of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`) and you can use json_encode in the same way as before